# Display data at Default.aspx after secure Login Using label, text box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I want to display Data after Secure Login. Using Label and textboxes. And also want to use session variable to expire login.
My problem is that. how to display this data in user Home page.

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEmployeeDetail](
    [EmployeeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Telephone] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [HouseNo] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Street] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Locality] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Pincode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblEmployeeDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: where is your data ? show your code to retrieve data

Comment: Post what's the problem that you are facing exactly.

Comment: My problem is that. how to display this data in user Home page. just like facebook, when we login we get only our data not others.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook basically shows the data of your friends, the pages u liked, or the links u posted, commented or liked. That means each data what is are getting in your page is somehow related with you. It is basically the relationship between all these tables where the data is managed. **Use join** on the bases of userId and user friends userIds, you will get all the data you require.